# Index a mysql table (grid search)

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a mysql table `my_table`, which has the following column:

```
start_cell, end_cell, field_1, field_2, field_3 ..., field_n
```

Most of the time, I want to do something like:

```
select * from my_table where start_cell = 'cell_1234' and end_cell = 'cell_5678'
```

`start_cell` and `end_cell` are both from `cell_1` to `cell_9000`

I did the following index to speed up the search:

```
alter table my_table add index(start_cell)
```

This works fine so far. However, I am wondering if there is any better index approach for this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you usually test both columns in the queries, you should create a multi-column index.

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD INDEX (start_cell, end_cell);
```

This index will also be effective for queries that just test `start_cell`, since a multi-column index is also an index for any prefix of the index (this is a natural consequence of B-tree indexes).

If you also need to optimize queries that test `end_cell` without `start_cell`, you can add a second index:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD INDEX (end_cell);
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit broad, you should take jbto consideration the field types that start_cell and end_cell are
Any other usage, other than a simple `select *`
using join or group by
indexes can sometimes be more useful, if the combine more than one field, though it does not seem to be the case

In general, the best way to check proper indexing is to use explain select, i.e:

```
EXPLAIN select * from my_table where start_cell = 'cell_1234' and end_cell = 'cell_5678'
```

It will show you the weak points of your query, and will be able to point you to the best approach 
[MySQL explain select](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain.html)